# knockout.js: can I catch an event before value update that allows me to stop the update?

Tags: javascript, events, knockout.js, onchange

I know I can catch a keydown event on an input box and return false from the handler to stop the key press from being applied to an input box. I'd like to do something on a higher level with knockout bindings, i.e., I want to stop an update that is about to happen, say, after checking that the value typed in the input box would be illegal. I don't want the illegal value be applied to my view-model and then I would have to undo it "manually". I want to stop it before the view model is changed in any way.

Another real use-case I am having is, I want to change something about the view-model before the input is being applied to it. For example, I might want to save a copy of the present state before updating it.

How can I do this within the knockout framework? I could possibly handle mounsedown or focus events to prepare to save the value and then let the update happen and then undo it if needed, but I want to stop the update itself.

Here is what I tried:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Initial Write Protect Example</title>
    <script src="knockout-3.5.0.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
const data = {
    value: ko.computed({
        owner: this,
        read: function() { return "foo"; },
        write: function(x) { console.log("writing: " + x); debugger; }
    }),
};
let allowKey = true;

const changeFn       = function(x)  { console.log("changed: ",         x, data.value());  debugger; return false; };
const beforeChangeFn = function(x)  { console.log("about to change: ", x, data.value());  debugger; return false; };
const keydownFn      = function(x,event) { console.log("keydown: " + event.key + " allow? " + allowKey); return allowKey; };
const keyupFn        = function(x,event) { console.log("keyupn: "  + event.key);                         return false; };
    </script>   
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <span>Current Value:</span>
      <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
      <br/>
      <input data-bind="value: value,
                        event:{
                            change:       changeFn,
                            beforeChange: beforeChangeFn,
                            keydown:      keydownFn,
                            keyup:        keyupFn
                        }"></input>   
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">ko.applyBindings(data);</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

From this it is clear that while I can stop a key to take effect (setting allowKey to false in the debugger), I cannot stop the change, no beforeChange event is sent (it's mentioned once in the ko source code, so I figured I'd try it), and the change event comes after the ko.observable write. So, it's too late, the view model was already changed when the change event fires.

I guess I can go into the knockout source code to fix myself a nice beforeChange event whose return value of false would stop the further processing (and actually revert the value in the input box to what it was before.) But I wonder isn't there already some way I should go instead?

**UPDATE**:

I have now learned that I can subscribe to the beforeChange event for an observable:

```
observable.subscribe((newValue, eventName) => handle(newValue, eventName, 'beforeChange');
```

I made the two arguments here explicit to point out that the new value is not available in these handlers. This is a shame, because I need the new value too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can use a writable computed to prevent updates from propagating to your source observable.

You can use an extender to make it easy to reuse. I wrote the extender to accept a predicate function that takes a single string and returns either true or false. Depending on what you want to do with it, you might want to support a predicate that takes `prevValue` and `nextValue`. That would result in `validator(target(), str)`.

Note: it can be a bad user experience for people to have an unresponsive input field, so make sure to provide feedback to the user typing in the input field.

```js
ko.extenders.validate = function(target, validator) {
  return ko.computed({
    read: target,
    write: str => {
      if (!validator(str)) {
        console.log(`Attempt to update ${data()} to ${str}, which is invalid.`);
        target.notifySubscribers(true);
      } else data(str);
    }
  }).extend({ notify: "always" });
}


const data = ko.observable("bdfgh");

ko.applyBindings({ 
  data: data.extend({ validate: charsAreInAlphabeticalOrder })
});

function charsAreInAlphabeticalOrder(str) {
  if (str.length <= 1) return true;
  
  return (
    str[0].localeCompare(str[1]) === -1 &&
    charsAreInAlphabeticalOrder(str.slice(1))
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label>
  Enter characters alpabetically
  <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: data">
</label>
```